# return outside selection что делать?

Tags: python, bs4, return

Код не запускается из-за return, подскажите почему так и как это исправить, буду очень благодарен

```
def get_all_pages():

    headers = {
        'user-agent' :'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36'
        }
    
r = requests.get(url='https://winauto.ua/index.php?match=all&subcats=y&pcode_from_q=y&pshort=y&pfull=y&pname=y&pkeywords=y&search_performed=y&q=gazer&dispatch=products.search&items_per_page=128&search_id=37901&page=1')
if not os.path.exists("data"):
        os.mkdir("data")

with open("data/page_1.html", "w") as file:
        file.write(r.text)
with open("data/page_1.html") as file:
        src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

pages_count = int(soup.find("div", class_="ty-pagination__items").find_all(class_="cm-history ty-pagination__item cm-ajax")[-1].text)

for i in range(1,pages_count + 1):

    url = f'https://winauto.ua/index.php?match=all&subcats=y&pcode_from_q=y&pshort=y&pfull=y&pname=y&pkeywords=y&search_performed=y&q=gazer&dispatch=products.search&items_per_page=128&search_id=37901&page={i}'

    r = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)

    with open(f'data/page_{i}.html','w') as file:
        file.write(r.text)
        time.sleep(4)
        return pages_count + 1
```

Comment: А к чему у вас return относится? если ваш код выглядит именно так, как показано в вопросе, то это не код, а белиберда

Comment: Здравствуйте, это не весь код, а функция в которой выбивает ошибку

Comment: https://replit.com/@Konstantin-Niko/Parcer#main.py вот весь код

Comment: Ну так у вас иденты кривые. Если у вас в вопросе только одна функция, отформатируйте ее как положено, чтобы было понятно, что у вас к чему относится.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, спасибо за помощь!